# IsPrime Function bug?

Tags: python

I wrote this function to check if a number is prime. It seems to work fine by itself however when I use it in another function, it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my IsPrime function:

```
def is_prime(n):
    boolean = False
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
            return True
    for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

The function below calculates the sum of all the primes under 2000000:

```
def problem10(prime, result):
    if prime > 2000000:
        return 
    if is_prime(prime):
        print 'prime is ', prime 
        result = result + prime
        problem10(prime + 1, result)
    return result
```

I can't understand where I have gone wrong.

Comments will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when the number is not prime?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "does not seem to work."

Comment: Also, why do you recursively call problem10 with the next number in question? The for loop must be much more efficient and will not cause stack overflow

Answer (score 6):

`is_prime` is not checking for even numbers. For instance, if you passed it 4, it would see that it's neither 2 nor 3, then proceed to the loop, which would execute once, checking if it's even divisible by 3 (which it's not). Exiting the loop, it would return `True`, when we know that 4 is, actually, not prime.

Comment: @thg435 this is not the only wrong thing in the OP's code. There is an obvious error also in the "problem10" code.

Answer (score 3):

You have a bug in the flow of your `problem10` function. It boils down to the fact that you do not actually use the result value of your recursive `problem10` function. You want your code to look something like this (assuming you want to keep your recursion, you may want to consider a loop instead):

```
def problem10(prime):
    """ calculates the sum of primes from this prime until 2000000 (2 * 10**6) """
    if prime >= 2000000:
       return 0
    elif is_prime(prime):
       return prime + problem10(prime + 1)
    else:
       return problem10(prime + 1)
```

Note that this function approach has several key points to consider:

1. If prime >= 2000000, then this function represents the empty sum. Therefore return 0.
2. If is_prime(prime), then this function should add prime to the sum
3. Otherwise the sum is the same as the sum of primes from the next number (because we have to exclude the lower number anyway because it is not a prime).
4. In comparison with your original attempt: note how using an expression in the return statement considerably simplifies the logic (flow) of your function. It's really a lot more readable. Also, notice how your original function could never have worked because:

   a. your function does not update the running total (result)

   b. an even if it did, eventually you would end up adding `None` to something because your original function returned nothing in the the prime >= 2000000 case.

Comment: I ran your code however it still gave me a maximum recursion depth error.

Comment: That is nothing strange your upper limit is 2000000, aka 2 million, and you require one recursion per number. So you require approximately 2 million recursions and each recursion requires a bit of stack. Python has a built in limit to recursion to protect you from the consequences of running out of stack space. That is why (among other things) you want to consider a loop as it does not come with these problems and limits.

Answer (score 1):

A faster prime number list is something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def primesfrom2to(n):
    """ Returns a array of primes, p < n """
    assert n>=2
    sieve = np.ones(n/2, dtype=np.bool)
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i/2]:
            sieve[i*i/2::i] = False
    return np.r_[2, 2*np.nonzero(sieve)[0][1::]+1]
```

Then just the sum of that:

```
print sum(primesfrom2to(2000000))
```

If you want to use your function, here is a suggested rewrite:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n in (2,3):
        return True
    if not n%2:
        return False        
    if any(n%x == 0 for x in xrange(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2)):     
        return False   
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a correct version of your is_prime function, which uses trial division by 2 and the odd numbers from 3 to the square root of *n* to determine if n is prime or composite:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2
    d = 3
    while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            return False
        d += 2
    return True
```

A better way to solve the problem is to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to identify all the primes less than 2000000, then sum them.  Here's a simple Sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
def sieve(n):
    b, p, ps = [True] * (n+1), 2, []
    for p in xrange(2, n+1);
        if b[p]:
            ps.append(p)
            for i in xrange(p+p, n+1, p):
                b[i] = False
    return ps
```

There are better (faster) ways both to determine if a number is prime or composite and to generate a list of all the prime numbers, but these are sufficient for your task.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be checking the range as so

```
for x in range(2, sqrt(n)+1):
    if n % x == 0:
        return False
```

No root will ever be larger than the square root.

Comment: This is incorrect: you _do_ have to check the square root. If you use the floor of `n**.5` as "stop" in the range, it wont be included and thus you miss the squares of a prime.
If you meant this, then it's not clear from the example code.

Comment: `n**0.5` does exactly that. `import math.sqrt` is faster, however.

Comment: @Bakuriu That's my bad forgot range(2, sqrt(n)) wouldn't include the sqrt itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPrime(num,div=2):
if(num==div):
    return True
elif(num % div == 0):
    return False
else:
    return isPrime(num,div+1)
```